# How will I set a restriction for the user to input a 4 digit codes only?

Tags: c++

I am creating a program that prompts the user to input 4 digits. The program should not accept less than 4 digit codes, greater than 4 digit codes, negative digit codes, and characters. If the user input less than or greater than 4 digit codes, negative and characters, it shall display an error sign.

How can I set restrictions in my program? I tried using if statement for the less than 4 digit codes and greater than 4 digit codes. The greater than 4 digit codes works but I don't know how to do it on the less than 3 codes. I also cannot figure it out if the user input a character instead of a 4 digit codes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you.

Comment: Read the input data as a string.  Check if the content of that string is a valid 4-digit code.   If it isn't, display an "error sign" and discard the string.  Keep doing that until a valid 4-digit code has  been read.

Comment: It's common when encountering a problem of digits to think "I shall read an integer, then". If the digits don't designate a number but some kind of code, or need validation, reading them as a string is usually the simplest way.

Answer (score -1):

You can't take away characters from the user's keyboard, so often the best way is to just read in a string and parse that string.

Comment: Okay. I'll research on that.

Comment: `if (line.length() == 4 && isdigit(line[0]) && isdigit(line[1]) && isdigit(line[2]) && isdigit(line[3])) // happy path...`

Comment: @Eljay: No `std::all_of` ? Why hardcode the length?

Comment: You actually can "take away characters", but that would be not portable C++, since terminal IO is system-dependent. But in any case, you can turn off terminal echo and read input char by char, only accepting and echoing the valid characters.

Comment: @MSalters • as per OP's requirement, the length has to be exactly 4.  `std::all_of` would work to ensure each character is a digit.  Or using a `std::regex` could do both (although some people are regex adverse, but I like 'em).